# Large print/echo break http response

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, wamp

I am having a problem with an echo/print that returns a large amount of data. The response is broken and is as follows:

- end of data
- http response header printed in body
- start of data

I am running the following script to my browser to replicate the problem:

```
<?php

// Make a large array of strings
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
{        
  $arr[] = "testing this string becuase it is must longer than all the rest to see if we can replicate the problem. testing this string becuase it is must longer than all the rest to see if we can replicate the problem. testing this string becuase it is must longer than all the rest to see if we can replicate the problem.";
}

// Create one large string from array
$var = implode("-",$arr);

// Set HTTP headers to ensure we are not 'chunking' response
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($var)); 
header('Content-type: text/html');

// Print response
echo $var;

?>
```

**What is happening here?**

**Can someone else try this?**

Answer (score 0):

You might have automatic output buffering activated on your server. If the buffer overflows, it just starts pooping out the rest of the data instead.

Note that something like gzip compression also implicitly buffers the output. If it's the case, an `ob_end_flush()` call after the headers should solve it.

Comment: I have tried adding ob_end_flush(); at the end of my script and the problem is the same.

Comment: Not at the end, between the headers and the `echo` statement.

Comment: Tried that, and the same problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Browsers often limits the characters you're allowed to pass through a get variable.
To work around this, you could base 64 encode the string, and then decode it, once you recievede the respone.

I think there's javascript base 64 encode libraries available.
Like this one:
http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Comment: Hi, I am not passing any values through a get variable. This script actually error while just viewing it in a browser.